# spring security unsupported configuration attributes hasRole(), permitAll after spring upgrade

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am upgrading spring security (and many other spring libraries) from version 3 to version 4 using this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-migrate-3-to-4/compare/xml?expand=1 commit as a reference.

When the application server (tomcat) starts, several errors regarding to spring appears:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [8]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('SUPERADMIN'), hasRole('ADMIN'), hasRole('USER'), permitAll]
```

Here is my spring-security.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

<import resource="businessContext.xml"/>
<!-- Spring security configs -->

<bean id="valuUserDetailsService" class="com.xxx.business.remote.ValuUserDetailsService">
    <property name="userService" ref="userService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="valuPasswordEncoderService" class="com.xxx.business.remote.ValuPasswordEncoderService">
</bean>

<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="valuUserDetailsService"/>
    <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="valuPasswordEncoderService"/>
</bean>    

<sec:authentication-manager>   
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="daoAuthenticationProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>       

<!-- Note: use IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY for any target that is allowed to be accessed anonymously. The patterns are matched in the listed order. -->
<sec:http disable-url-rewriting="false" use-expressions="false" create-session="always">
    <sec:headers disabled="true"/>
    <sec:csrf disabled="true"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/remoteservices/superadmin/**" access="hasRole('SUPERADMIN')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/remoteservices/admin/**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/remoteservices/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/rest/401" access="permitAll"/>
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="hasRole('USER')"/>
    <sec:http-basic/>
</sec:http>
</beans>
```

It has a little modifications after the library upgrade but otherwise this same file worked with spring 3. Any ideas what would be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By explicitly setting `use-expressions="false"` you are disabling the use of expressions in the 'access' attributes in <intercept-url>.

Since `hasRole('SUPERADMIN')`, `permitAll` etc are expressions, there is an exception thrown saying that they are unsupported.

You can either set `use-expressions` to `true`, which is the default, or change the rule to state `<sec:intercept-url pattern="/remoteservices/superadmin/**" access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN"/>`.

This is described in detail in the [Migrate <http>](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-http) section of the migration guide.

Note that Spring Security 4 has reached its end of life since [October 2020](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/Spring-Security-Versions). I would advise you to migrate to a supported version of Spring Security 5 as soon as possible.